# Powershell script to replace with regex is not working

Tags: regex, powershell

I have the following script which reads in a file line by line and replaces a pattern in each line with specified text, then writes this to another file:

```
param
(
    [string] $inFilePath,
    [string] $outFilePath,
    [string] $inputPattern,
    [string] $replacePattern
)

function Main()
{
    $sr = $null;
    $sw = $null;

    try
    {
        $sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($inFilePath);
        $sw = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($outFilePath, $true);
        do
        {
            $fileLine = $sr.ReadLine();
            $fileLine2 = "";
            if ($fileLine -eq $null)
            {
                break;
            }
            $fileLine = $fileLine + [System.Environment]::NewLine;
            $fileLine2 = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace($fileLine, $inputPattern, $replacePattern);
            $sw.Write($fileLine2);
        }
        while ($fileLine -ne $null);
    }
    finally
    {
        $sr.Dispose();
        $sw.Dispose();
    }
}

Main;
```

Unfortunately, when I save the script as filereplace.ps1 and call it like this:

`powershell .\filereplace.ps1 c:\docs\infile.txt c:\docs\outfile.txt '.{30,}\->.*\r\n' '*'`

I get this error:

`The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? I suspect there is something wrong with the regex pattern used in searching for a replacement - when I remove the `\->`, it works, but there is no reason why this should be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the redirection operator `>` that causes the problem in the command line. Enclose the whole command with `"`:

```
powershell ".\filereplace.ps1 c:\docs\infile.txt c:\docs\outfile.txt '.{30,}\->.*\r\n' '*'"
```